# Saving file created inside the view to the backend (Django)

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-file-upload

I have the following model :

```
def upload_to(instance, filename):

    return os.path.join('/%s/' % instance.user.username, filename)

class UserAudioAnswer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    audio_file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to)
    translated_english_answer = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    my_points = models.IntegerField(default=-1)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question.text
```

Inside my view I am recording an audio file from the user as follows:

```
def start_recording(r,request):

    print("Reached start recording metho. About to start recording")

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Say something!")
        audio = r.record(source,duration=5)
    return audio
```

My MEDIA_ROOT is defined as below:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_in_env", "media_root")
```

So in this media_root folder I have to create a folder with the user name and then save the file inside it. I created the upload_to function to save my file there.

I have done the following:

1)

```
user_audio_answer = UserAudioAnswer()
user_audio_answer.audio_file.save = (random_file_name,File(f))
                    user_audio_answer.audio_file = settings.MEDIA_ROOT+"/"+request.user.username+"/"+random_file_name+".flac"
```

but it does not save anything.

2) `user_audio_answer.audio_file = settings.MEDIA_ROOT+"/"+request.user.username+"/"+random_file_name+".flac"`

It saves the path of the file but the path starts from /Users/username/desktop and it goes on.

What is the correct way to save the file to my backend, the way I am doing it?`